# MVC parsing localized input - Model? Controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, parsing, localization, model, internationalization

I'm currently working with PHP (CodeIgniter) and I was wondering if I should parse localized input in the Model or Controller? I'm leaning towards Models since parsing would come after/mixed with validation. (which is in the model, no?)

I can't help but get a certain uneasiness in regards to re-usability from clumping everything in the model (validation, parsing/localization, arranging, cache, database, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I usually do input validation / filtering in controllers to reduce the depth of function call stack (so errors get caught more immediately), it's perfectly legal to have them in models however.

Anyway, here's a clue: Is the input parsing process part of the business logic? If so, then it's better to have it in the model. Otherwise (the business logic only cares about the parsed input), I suggest to put it in controller (or helper).

Comment: Could you give me an example of when input parsing would be part of the business logic? For example, I'm dealing with listings, and I guess it wouldn't be -- but if validation goes in the model and transforming localized input is dependent on validation...

Comment: I don't have any idea, never face such a case (my inputs were always simple values that need no further processing other than validation). Could you tell me what kind of parsing would you need to do against the input data and what the input data looks like?